# Confusion over set theory notation and finding the no. of even subsets

Tags: notation

A question states, " Let $S$ be an even set, $\{1,2,3,4....n\}$ such that $n>2$.
Let $S_1,S_2,\dotsc,S_n$ be even subsets of $S$"
This implies there has to be some order of listing the subsets. What is that order?
Also, For an even set of $n$ members, there are $2^{n-1}$ even subsets.Then why is the last subset $S_n$?

Comment: What's an "even set", to begin with?

Comment: a set containing even no. of elements

Comment: It's quite reasonable that you are puzzled, because this is a very badly-written question.

Comment: now that I think about, the second part isn't wrong, it's just considering n subsets out of a total of 2^(n-1) possible even subsets. However, I still don't know what S1, S2, S3.... correspond to

Comment: All you have told us is the **hypothesis** of a problem. We are **given** an even set $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with $n\gt2$ and $n$ even subsets of $S$ labeled $S_1,S_2,\dots,S_n$. It would be interesting to know what we are supposed to prove or find from that. How about telling us the rest of the question?

Comment: prove there exists some i and j such that 1<j<_n and the intersection of Si and Sj is an even set

Comment: I have an approach,

Comment: if I can somehow prove Si and Sj are disjoint, then Their intersection will be the null set, which will be even. But then again, I Don't know what Si and Sj correspond to!